# Repository mocking doesn`t work. Return wrong Http status

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have `createUser()` method in my **`UsserServiceImpl.java`**

```java
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = new User(userDto.getName(), userDto.getProducts(), getCurrentDate(), null);
        user = repository.save(user);
        return user != null ? new ResponseEntity<>(convertToDto(user), HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I have a unit test for this method

```java
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void init() {
    userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository);
}

@Test
void createUser() {
    Set<Product> productSet = createProducts();
    LocalDate date = getCurrentDate();
    User user = new User("Max", productSet, date, null);

    when(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(new User(UUID.fromString("e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0"), "Max", productSet, date, null));

    ResponseEntity<UserDto> userDto = userService.createUser(new UserDto("Max", productSet));

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, userDto.getStatusCode());
    assertEquals(userDto.getBody(), new UserDto("Max", productSet));
}
```

When I execute test I get an `\error:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:  Expected :200 OK Actual   :400
>   BAD_REQUEST

as I understand, the problem is that `repository.save()` the method returns null.
I totally don`t understand why this string

```
when(userRepository.save(user))
 .thenReturn(
   new User(UUID.fromString("e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0"), 
   "Max", 
   productSet, 
   date, 
   null)
 );
```

doesn`t work properly, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there are 2 `User` objects being involved in this scenario. Inside `createUser()` at runtime, there is a new `User` object will be created. That `User` object is not equal to the `User` object you create when you write the Mock statement. Therefore, you can accept any arbitrary `User` object when you define the mock statement.

```
Mockito.any(User.class)
```

If you intend those 2 objects to be equal; `User` class should provide a  proper `equals()` implementation. It seems it doesn't provide such a implementation. So, you can try something like below.

```
    when(userRepository.save(any(User.class)))
   .thenReturn(
      new User(UUID.fromString("e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0"), 
              "Max", 
              productSet, 
              date, 
              null)
   );
```